# SetMyLocation(true) isn't showing blue circle on 5.0 but yes on 4.0.3

Tags: android, google-maps, location, maps, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using the v2 API of Google Maps and need to show my location, to do so, I have this code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

It is working well on Android 4.0.3 but on a 5.0 the blue circle that point my location isn't visible at all. Any ideas?

Comment: It worked on 5.1.1 for me...Did you enable location on your 5.0 device?

Comment: You were right, was that stupid thing...Thanks. I've spent all the day with that...what a dumb haha